# Dates returned as #error in SRSS report from SharePoint list

Tags: reporting-services

I have connected an SRSS report (in SQL Reporting Services 2012) to a SharePoint 2013 list. Date fields all return `#error`, but other fields return data successfully. May query looks like this:

```
<RSSharePointList xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ListName>Absence Records</ListName>
  <ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name="StaffMemberName" />
    <FieldRef Name="Reason" />
    <FieldRef Name="Year" />
    <FieldRef Name="Start" />
    <FieldRef Name="End" />
  </ViewFields>
</RSSharePointList>
```

The start and end fields are date fields, and these return `#error`. The other fields return the expected data in the query designer. The same is seen in the tablix when the report is run. I have no idea why this is happening nor how to get dates to return.

Comment: What function/formula are you applying to the field in the report? (I have reports that use date fields without any issues)

Comment: I'm not using any. I am just trying to show the data as it comes in a tablix. I expected this to work. I have experience of writing reports from SQL server but not form SharePoint. I thought it could be the dates need formatting in some way or the way they are stored in SharePoint may need addressing. Thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

For **dates** you need to use the **Format** attribute, with one of these values:

- **DateOnly**: Only display (and allow edits to) the date portion (the time portion is set to 12:00 A.M. for all edited values).
- **DateTime**: Display and edit both date and time of day (default).
- **ISO8601**   Display date and time in ISO8601 time format converted to UTC: YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ.

You check the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543225(v=office.15).aspx).